# Reverse Proxy Sending "Internal Server Error" When Sent Non-Standard HTTP Status Code

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

We're running a JBoss web service behind a reverse proxy, using Apache 2.2.21 on OpenSuSE 12.1. All the services return standard HTTP status codes except for one situation, where we wanted to indicate a particular condition, so we used a non-standard status code, 210.

Everything works as expected except for the one condition where we return 210. After some investigation, I ran wireshark on the connection between JBoss and the proxy, and saw that JBoss was indeed returning 210, but that the proxy was returning 500.

I've tried increasing the Apache log level to debug, but nothing appears in the logs when the error occurs. I've looked on the web for any information about returning non-standard status codes through mod_proxy, with no success.

I'd like to avoid stepping through the Apache code in a debugger, and was wondering if anybody had come across anything like this before.

Here's my proxy configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com

    # don't loose time with IP address lookups
    HostnameLookups Off

    # needed for named virtual hosts
    UseCanonicalName Off

    # Avoid open your server to proxying
    ProxyRequests Off

    # Let apache correctly rewrite redirect
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyErrorOverride Off

    # Let apache pass the original host not the ProxyPass one
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.